# Multiplicative inverse

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Explain why 1/i is − i.

(That is: explain why the multiplicative inverse of i is the complex number − i.)

And then the hint that I was given was, what property deﬁnes the multiplicative inverse?

I know how to algebraically prove 1/i = -i, but need help writing the proof.

Comment: What is your definition for $i\,$?

Comment: My definition is i^2=-1

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of multiplicative inverse, $1/i$ satisfies $(1/i)i=1$. Presumably you know that $i^2=-1$. Then you have that $$(-i)i=-i^2=1=(1/i)i$$ By cancellation, $-i=1/i$.

Answer (score 0):

$i^2=-1$ is the definition of i. Thus,
$$i*-i=--1=1$$
The multiplicative inverse is simply whatever you multiply by to get the identity, thus it is proved!